# When does Go language type inference happen?

Tags: go, compilation

```
var (
    HOME = os.Getenv("HOME")
    USER = os.Getenv("USER")
    GOROOT = os.Getenv("GOROOT")
)
```

Are the types of these variables determined during compilation or at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go is a statically typed language, so it must happen at compile time.

[Spec: Variable declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

> If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise, each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization value in the assignment. If that value is an untyped constant, it is first implicitly [converted](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to its [default type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants); if it is an untyped boolean value, it is first implicitly converted to type `bool`. The predeclared value `nil` cannot be used to initialize a variable with no explicit type.
>
> ```
> var d = math.Sin(0.5)  // d is float64
> var i = 42             // i is int
> var t, ok = x.(T)      // t is T, ok is bool
> var n = nil            // illegal
> ```

In your example since return type of [`os.Getenv()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv) is `string`, all those variables will be of type `string`.